# How is a TFTP server supposed to handle duplicate ACK messages and duplicate DATA messages from a client?

Tags: server, client, ack, tftp

I'm creating a TFTP server and trying to figure out how I need to handle duplicate ACK messages received from the client and duplicate DATA messages received from the client based on the TFTP protocol: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1350#ref-4